# How to use describe 'table_name' in HBase shell to create a table.

Tags: shell, hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, bigdata

I have to create a table in different cluster and i only have description of hbase table as handy. how do i create the new hbase table in different cluster?

Answer (score 2):

go to hbase shell by typing `Hbase shell` in terminal in you new cluster, then give command `create ‘<table name>’,’<column family>’`  give you table name and column family name which you already have from `describe 'table name'` from previous cluster.

for more info:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_create_table.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_describe_and_alter.htm